# Bind ButterKnife to Dialog fails

Tags: android, butterknife

I try to bind ButterKnife to a AleterDialog that i made with a DialogBuilder method
And exist this method `ButterKnife.bind(Object,Dialog);` but dosen't work for me

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
public class NewUserDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Bind(R.id.textuserAccount)
    EditText textuserAccount;
    @Bind(R.id.textPassword)
    EditText textPassword;
    @Bind(R.id.nauta_domains)
    Spinner nauta_domains;
    @Bind(R.id.manualConfig)
    View manualConfig;
    @Bind(R.id.checkViewPass)
    CheckBox checkViewPass;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.new_user_dialog__icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.new_user_dialog_title)
                .setView(R.layout.accountlist_dialog_user_)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_create, void_OnClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, void_OnClickListener)
                .create();
      //Fails!!!!!!!
        ButterKnife.bind(this,dialog);  
    ...
```

ERROR:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'textuserAccount' with ID 2131624044 for field 'textuserAccount' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.
                                                                                      at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
```

and `textuserAccount = (EditText) ((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.textuserAccount);` works perfectly

I can use butterknife somehow in this class?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to inflate your dialog layout and pass the resulting View object to butterknife.

```
    view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.accountlist_dialog_user_, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
```

At least, that's how I've used Butterknife in dialogs and it works fine for me.

Comment: OK the final solution  is pass this inflated view to dialog : `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())...setView(view)`

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to bind views in `onStart` of the `DialogFragment` (similarly to [this sample app](https://github.com/kubode/KotlinMVVM/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/teamlab/kotlin/mvvm/ui/views/AddAccountDialogFragment.kt)), while still using the `AlertDialog.Builder#setView(int)` method:

```
private Unbinder unbinder;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.new_user_dialog__icon)
            .setTitle(R.string.new_user_dialog_title)
            .setView(R.layout.accountlist_dialog_user)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_create, void_OnClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, void_OnClickListener)
            .create();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, getDialog());
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And everything works perfect

`Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_outcome);
Unbinder unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, dialog);`