# Exception When handling Custom AlertDialog with ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, exception, android-alertdialog, butterknife

Hello guys iam realy Confused i spent over 17 hours try to fix this Problem but 
No hope

Am try to show Custom Dialog  with  `> AlertDialog.Builder`  when i Click Button but when i run the App and click the button it gives me this Exception

i tried `ButterKnife @OnClick Anotation`   and Casting the Item Inside the Dialog Function  like `Button item = findviewById(R.id.ItemID);`

i search for questions has same problem like mine but useless  till i found 
this question [Multiple injections](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/145#issuecomment-44589260) but i found that its really very old `May 29, 2014`

The Exception

```
05-23 21:15:56.630 8769-8769/com.w4ma.soft.tamenly E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.w4ma.soft.tamenly, PID: 8769
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.w4ma.soft.tamenly.View.CreateandShow.ShowThePost.ShowCommentDialog(ShowThePost.java:133)
        at com.w4ma.soft.tamenly.View.CreateandShow.ShowThePost.onClick(ShowThePost.java:159)
        at com.w4ma.soft.tamenly.View.CreateandShow.ShowThePost_ViewBinding$1.doClick(ShowThePost_ViewBinding.java:52)
        at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Here is my code

> ShowThePost.java

```
    @Nullable   @BindView(R.id.priceSuggested)   EditText txtSuggestprice;
    @Nullable   @BindView(R.id.txtnotes)  EditText txtNotes;
    @Nullable   @BindView(R.id.btnClose)  Button btnclose;
    @Nullable   @BindView(R.id.btnCommentDone)  Button btndone;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_the_post);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


    }

    public void ShowCommentDialog() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_comment,null);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setView(view);

        final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();

//        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
//        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.create_comment);
//        dialog.setCancelable(false);
//        dialog.setTitle("This is Dialog");

//      EditText  txtSuggestprice = findViewById(R.id.priceSuggested);
//        EditText txtNotes = findViewById(R.id.txtnotes);
//       Button btnDonee = (Button)findViewById( R.id.btnCommentDone);
//     Button   btnClosee =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

//
//        btndone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//
//            }
//        });
//        btnclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                dialog.dismiss();
//
//            }
//        });

        final String Notes = txtNotes.getText().toString();
        final String Description = txtSuggestprice.getText().toString();

        alert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Toasty.success(context,"Done" + Notes + Description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        btndone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();

     }

@OnClick(R.id.fabComment) 
    public void ShowDialog(){

    ShowCommentDialog();

}
```

> CreatComment.xml    this is the Custom Dialog which should Inflate to the Dialog

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_12sdp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comment"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_22sdp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_9sdp"
            android:typeface="serif"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"
            android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/priceSuggested"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:hint="Suggest Price"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:typeface="serif"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:hint="Notes"
            android:id="@+id/txtnotes"
            android:typeface="serif"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            android:background="@drawable/btncommentstyle"
            android:id="@+id/btnCommentDone"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Close"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/btncommentstyle"
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: what is line 133 in class ShowThePost?

Comment: i'm guessing from the exception it's `final String Notes = txtNotes.getText().toString();`

Comment: it refuse any item inside the  Dialog or any fuction 

final String Notes = txtNotes.getText().toString();  is just to get the text in the Edittext but  when i removed it  the dialog works and showed Successfully  with the Items

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by this line:
`final String Notes = txtNotes.getText().toString();`

As described in the reason, the `txtNotes` member is `null`, which means that the binding did not work (probably the view with `txtnotes` id was not found).

From what I see, you call `ButternKnife.bind()` for the activity which has the `activity_show_the_post` layout as content view. But the view with `txtnotes` id is actually in the `create_comment` layout, of which ButterKnife knows nothing about, and doesn't even exist at that time. Thus, the binding fails, no reference to `txtnotes` is created and you later get a NPE.

Comment: thats right but how could i handle this in the View i tried to make an Object Twice  in Views   like ButterKnife.bind(this,view) inside the AlertDialog    but didn't successful

Comment: You need to bind to the layout that contains those IDs.  

In this case, you should use `bind(java.lang.Object target, android.app.Dialog source)` to use the ActivityDialog as the view root (source) for binding to the fields annotated in your activity (target).

Comment: according to the accepted answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173221/bind-butterknife-to-dialog-fails you need to perform the binding after inflating the dialog view. In your example that would be a call to `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` just before `alert.setView(view);` in the `ShowCommentDialog()` method.

If that still does not work out, revert to plain old `findViewById()`, but call it on the view you are setting for the dialog. Example: `EditText txtNotes = view.findViewById(R.id.txtnotes);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the views for create_comment.xml too

```
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_comment,null);
    Butterknife.bind(view,this);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setView(view);
    final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
```